# Is it a bad Practice to apply OutputCache to a repository model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

All the examples i have read applied the OutputCache to Controller action methods. but now i have a repository method , which retrieve Active directory users.so i want to cache this model class such as :

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "long", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "term")]
public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term)
{
    List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV"))
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
```

And for accomplishing this i have to included the following inside my repository model class:-

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
```

So it is wrong or is it a bad practice to add a Cache setting & include `System.web.mvc + system.Web.UI, insdie a repository model class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So it is wrong or is it a bad practice to add a Cache setting &
>   include `System.web.mvc + system.Web.UI, insdie a repository model
>   class?

Not only it is bad practice but it won't work at all because the `OutputCache` attribute only has effect on controller actions in which the entire output gets cached. You could use [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) to cache the result of the method. So here you could first look at the cache whether there's a list of users stored in it and if it is not query the AD and cache the results back.

Comment: not sure if it will be work, since the AD users are retrieved faster now. and why it is a bad practice to use output cache inside model classes?

Comment: It's bad because you are tying your models with ASP.NET and it won't work because as I already explained in my answer the OutputCache attribute only makes sense on controller actions. If you put it on some other class it will have absolutely no effect at all.